# Design Pattern for an EEPROM burner

Tags: c++, c, design-patterns

I've built myself a basic EEPROM burner using a Teensy++ 2.0 for my PC bridge, and it's working great, but as I look to expand its compatibility, my code is getting rather hacky.  I'm looking for some advice for a proper design for making this code expandable.  I've taken a class in software design patterns, but it was awhile ago, and I'm currently drawing a blank.  Basically, here's the use case:

I have several methods, such as ReadByte(), WriteByte(), ProgramByte() (for FlashROMs that require a multi-byte write sequence in order to program), EraseChip(), etc. so basically I have an EEPROM pure virtual base class that gets implemented by concrete classes for each chip type that I want to support.  The tricky part is determining which chip type object to generate.  I'm currently using a pseudo-terminal front-end on the Teensy++ serial input, a basic command-line type interface with parameters, to send options like the chip type to the Teensy++.  The question is, is there a design pattern (in C/C++), something like a Factory Pattern, that would take a string input of the chip type (because that's what I'm getting from the user), and return an EEPROM object of the correct derived type, without having to manually create some big switch statement or something ugly like that where I'd have to add the new chip to a list any time I create a new chip derived class?  So something like:

public const EEPROM & GetEEPROM(const std::string & id)

and if I pass it the string "am29f032b" it returns a reference to an AM29F032B object, or if I pass it the string "sst39sf040" it returns a reference to an SST39SF040 object, which I could then call the previously mentioned functions on, and it would work for the specified chip.

This code will be run on an AVR microcontroller, so I can't have anything with a huge OOP overhead, but the particular microcontroller I'm using does have a relatively large amount of program flash and work RAM, so it's not like I'm trying to operate in 2kb, but I do have to keep in mind limited resources.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a *Pluggable Factory*. There's a [good description](http://adtmag.com/articles/2000/09/25/industrial-strength-pluggable-factories.aspx) here.    It's attributed to John Vlissides (1 of the [Gang of Four](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns)) and takes the Abstract factory pattern a few steps further.  This pattern happens to also be the architectural foundation of COM.

The usual way of implementing one in C++ is to maintain a static registry of abstract factories.  With judicious use of a few templates and static initialisers, you can wrap the whole lot up few lines of boiler-plate which you include in each concrete product (e.g. chip type).

The use of static initialisers allows a complete decoupling of concrete products from both the registry and the code wanting to create products, and has the possibility of implementing each as a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a singleton factory manager that keeps a map of string->factory object. Then each factory class would have a global instance that registers itself with the manager on startup.

I try to avoid globals in general, and singletons in particular, but any other approach would require some form of explicit list which you're trying to avoid. You will have to be careful with timing issues (you can't really assume anything about the order in which the various factories will be created).